# Laravel eloquent search on fields of related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent models as,

**User** : *users(id, username, password, email, status)*

**Profile** : *profiles(id, user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob)*

In the controller logic, I am eagerly loading the Profile model.

I can do this,

```
$user = User::with('Profile')->get();
```

or

```
$user = User::with('Profile')->where('status', '1')->get();
```

but how to do something like,

```
$user = User::with('Profile')->where('status', '1')->where('gender', 'Male')->get();
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

That's where `whereHas` comes in handy:

```
$user = User::with('Profile')->where('status', 1)->whereHas('Profile', function($q){
    $q->where('gender', 'Male');
})->get();
```

Basically it adds the condition that the user needs to have a profile with `gender = Male`

Comment: if I need to do "or where" to the related profile table how can I do this? will $q->orWhere('gender', 'Male') works?

Comment: Probably you want `orWhereHas('Profile', ...`

Comment: thanks, one more question, within the closure method if I need two or more "or where" conditions, then the following code does not works.

orWhereHas('Profile', function($q){
    $q->Where('field3', 'like', '%value%');
    $q->orWhere('field4', 'like', '%value%');
})

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: it returns all values without filtering, however if I use orWhereHas() method twice, having different $q->where() condition for each orWhereHas() method, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure you want `orWhereHas`? To me it would make more sense to get all users with status 1 *and* some other condition on the profile.

Comment: Yes i want to use it, the question was just a simplified version of my problem, actually i need to search columns from both of the models using "or where" conditions, as I am eagerly loading the dependent models so I was looking to search the fields from second loaded model as well. Thanks anyways, I have accepted your answers. :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, may I ask you to have a look at a  Laravel table join related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?

Comment: Thanks! This is I have looking for. An important detail is to use orWhereHas('Profile', ... if there is more than one where condition.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to search multiple columns in relation model.

```
        $searchText = 'test text';
        Product::with('owner')->where(function($query) use ($searchText)
        {
            $query->where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%');

            $columns = ['product_code', 'place_location', 'remark'];

            foreach ($columns as $column ) {
                $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%');
            }

            $query->orWhereHas('owner', function($q) use ($searchText) {
                $q->where(function($q) use ($searchText) {
                    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%');
                    $q->orWhere('company_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%');
                });
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you've multiple relations

and you want to search records based on multiple relational columns value

```
            User::with('associate')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $input . '%')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($input) {
                $query->whereHas('associate', function ($q) use ($input) {
                    $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $input . '%');
                });
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($input) {
                $query->with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($input) {
                    $q->where('display_name', 'like', '%' . $input . '%');
                });
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose, Your search input field name is q.

function name(Request $request){
$query = User::select();
if($request->q && $request->q !=''){
  // if you search 
       $keyword = $request->q;
       $query = User::with('Profile')->whereHas('Profile', function($q) use 
       ($keyword){
           $q->where('gender', 'like', "%{$keyword}%" );
       });
   }
$query->latest('id')->paginate();
}
```