# How to make associations based on multiple columns in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I am facing issue for creating assosications based on multiple columns. Here is my code and array :-

```
$getdetails =  OrdersProduct::with('getattributes')->get();
```

And My **OrdersProduct.php** Model file

```
public function getattributes(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\ProductsColor','product_id','product_id');
 }
```

See the array below:-

```
  Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 100015390
        [product_id] => 1203
        [product_size] => 12
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5748
                        [product_id] => 1203
                        [sku_website] => N7W84308-BLACK-10
                        [sku] => 8907613878595
                        [color] => 
                        [size] => 10
                        [price] => 2799
                        [stock] => 0
                        [ip_address] => 
                        [created_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:36
                        [updated_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:36
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5749
                        [product_id] => 1203
                        [sku_website] => N7W84308-BLACK-12
                        [sku] => 8907613878601
                        [color] => 
                        [size] => 12
                        [price] => 2799
                        [stock] => 0
                        [ip_address] => 
                        [created_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:37
                        [updated_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:37
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

My expected **output** is below:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 100015390
        [product_id] => 1203
        [product_size] => 12
        [attributes] => Array
            (

                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5749
                        [product_id] => 1203
                        [sku_website] => N7W84308-BLACK-12
                        [sku] => 8907613878601
                        [color] => 
                        [size] => 12
                        [price] => 2799
                        [stock] => 0
                        [ip_address] => 
                        [created_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:37
                        [updated_at] => 2018-08-07 16:15:37
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

I want to compare with product_id and product_size in order_products table form products_color table having product_id and size. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships) adds support for multi-columns relationships in Laravel 5's Eloquent.

It allows you to specify relationships using the following syntax:

```
public function b()
{
    return $this->hasMany('B', ['key1', 'key2'], ['key1', 'key2']);
}
```

where columns have to match.

Comment: you have copied from this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751859/laravel-5-hasmany-relationship-on-two-columns/49739512#49739512

Comment: I would like to see at what point you are comparing values. Please show.

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\ProductsColor', ['product_id', 'product_id'], ['product_size', 'size']);

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913014/laravel-eloquent-search-on-fields-of-related-model) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your **OrdersProduct** model :

```
public function getattributes(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\ProductsColor','product_id','product_id')->where('size',$this->product_size);
 }
```

Comment: please try now and reply

Answer (score 0):

Finally done. i have add the join in getattributes. Hope it will help others in future:-

```
$getdetails =  OrdersProduct::with(['getattributes'=>function($query){
        $query->join('orders_products','orders_products.product_size','=','products_colors.size');
    }])->get();
```

Comment: NO can you tell me how to do?