# How to search from multiple tables in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I search from multiple tables using laravel eloquent. below is my query.

```
$data= User::where('id',$search_str)
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search_str}%")
            ->with('usersecond:id,name,email')->get();
```

If I search for something I get results from the user table. how can I get results from usersecond table in this query?

Comment: is this your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913014/laravel-eloquent-search-on-fields-of-related-model

Comment: You can use [`orWhereExists`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereExists) to filter on a second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `whereHas()` function

```php
$data = User::where('id', $search_str)
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search_str}%")
    ->with('usersecond:id,name,email')
    ->orWhereHas('usersecond', function ($q) use ($search_str) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search_str}%");
    })->get();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence